# How to modify HTML rendered from server on Angular Component?

Tags: angular

I have a page which most part is rendered from server (inside `div.content`), since I want the content to be indexed on Google, and, as the content come from the database, it needs to be rendered before page loads.

I have two Angular components that in `click()`, I need to remove that `div.content` or change font color to that `div`.

I don't get how to do that to a div which is out of the component. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Content rendered from Server -->
</div>
<buttons></buttons>
```

Comment: What does "out of the component" mean?

Comment: Check out my edit, The component selector is `buttons`, the `content` div is not part of the component. How can I add a class or modify something?

Comment: What about `<div class="content" *ngIf="isClicked">`

Comment: But then, How can I change `isClient`, if the scope of the component is only inside `buttons`?

Comment: If the common parent must not be involved then you could create a directive and add it to `<div class="content" myDirective>` and connect `<buttons>` with `MyDirective` using a service to communicate from `Buttons` to `MyDirective` to change `isClicked`. I don't know how `*ngIf` and a directive on the same tag work together. But if this approach would work for you I could have a closer look. There is always `ElementRef` but especially if you use server rendering I guess this should be avoided.

Comment: Great, I guess that will work! I will try

Comment: Or how can you have a common parent? because when I create a component, it will erase all its contents right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Where would this `<div class="content">
    <!-- Content rendered from Server -->
</div>
<buttons></buttons>` live? It has to be in the template of a component, hasn't it?

Comment: That's the question! haha, if it is on the template of a component, it would be redered by angular (javascript), it wont be indexed by google

Comment: I guess you'd have to use Angulars server-side-rendering feature or use different template URLs on client and server. I don't think I can help you much here. I don't have experience with this feature.